# Опала от слова "опалить"?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Опала - это немилость вышестоящих. Слово явно происходит от "опалить". Вот только интересно,какая связь между этими словами?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

У Шанского приводится короткое пояснение:ОПАЛА - общеславянское, производное от opaliti - "обжечь". 
Наложить опалу - это именно обжечь своим гневом и наложить наказание, то есть каким-то чувствительным способом выразить свою немилость.